# como redireccionar wp-admin de wordpress en functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cms

Hola chic@s estoy investigando por la red y lo que parecia algo sencillo se está convirtiendo en un dolor de cabeza para mi. Estoy configurando un login personalizado para woocommerce y me encuentro con un problema. En mi archivo functions.php tengo lo siguiente (en la accion: ***add_action('init',funcion);***):

```
global $pagenow;
$action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
if( $pagenow == 'wp-login.php' && ( ! $action || ( $action && ! in_array($action, array('logout', 'lostpassword', 'rp', 'resetpass'))))) {
    $page = get_bloginfo('url');
    wp_redirect($page.'/404');
    exit();
}
```

Esto hace la típica redirección hacia la página 404 hasta ahí todo bien.

El problema real es que tengo un popup que realiza un checkout en la página wp-login con los siguientes códigos en el functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'funcion' );

add_action( 'authenticate', 'funcion');

add_filter('login_errors', 'funcion');
```

Omito el código porque no tiene relevancia para la pregunta. Y es la siguiente ¿exíste algún filtro/acción que ejecute el código de redirección al terminar de cargar la página si wp_login_failed, authenticate y login_errors no se ejecutaron previamente? Pensé en crear una variable global o incluso una variable de sesión para solucionar esto pero creo que no es lo más optimo. ¿que opinan?

Comment: Te refieres a que ejecute la redirección ni no hay una sesión activa?

Comment: No, me refiero a que se ejecute la redirección si no  se ejcutan wp_login_failed, authenticate y login_errors

Comment: es decir básicamente solo si el usuario escribe directamente en el navegador /wp-admin

Comment: También probe con plugins  pero tengo el mismo resultado por eso descarto plugins el tema es que quiero que el usuario tenga mejor experiencia con mi formulario de inicio de sesión

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es la siguiente: Hice un login en una ventana modal y la redirección del formulario era en wp-login.php lo que hice fue eliminar el actión del html de form para que enviara los datos en la misma página y ya me fué sin problema.

Antes:

```
<form name="login" action="dominio.com/wp-login.php" method="post">
```

Despues:

```
<form name="login" method="post">
```

No se si será lo ideal, pero funciona.